# How can one client.create_tweet a python variable using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm relatively new to this, but im looking to be able to tweet dictionary data (key:value) data using Tweepy.

For example:

```
response = requests.get("insertURLhere")

client.create_tweet(text=response)
```

Is this possible via Tweepy?

How can I go about grabbing URL data, and posting said data to a Twitter account via Tweepy?

Any insight is greatly appreciate.

I've attempted to assess Tweepy post options, but can't seem to find anything regarding ghe ability to post variables. I suspect there are some simple things im missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code snippet:

```
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Create a tweet
_URL = "https://api.quotable.io/random" # YOUR URL
message = requests.get(_URL).json()["content"]
client.create_tweet(text=message)
print("Tweeted!")
```

I hope this helps.